# Extracting Nibbles from Java Bytes

Tags: java, serial-port

```
Hex:[0A][52][08][01][01][01][00][CD][21][02][59]


0      [0A]
1      [52]         Packettype    = TEMP_HUM
2      [08]         subtype       = TH8 - 
3      [01]         Sequence nbr  = 1
4/5    [01][01]     ID            = 257
6/7    [00][CD]     Temperature   = 20.5 °C
8      [21]         Humidity      = 33
9      [02]         Status        = Dry
10     [5] *nibble           Signal level  = 5
11     [9] *nibble           Battery       = OK
```

So I get 11 bytes (Hex) in over the serial port.
I assigned all the bytes to a byte array so that I can use them later.

I have two qestions:

1] How can I combine the 4 & 5 bytes back together in Java (I am presuming in an INT) ?
2] How can you extract  10 and 11 or the High and Low nibbles of the last byte ?

[FROM COMMENTS BELOW]
Example Byte: High[0101][0110]Low
               lowNibble = yourbyte & 0x0f;
               01010110 & 0x0f (00001111) = 00000110

```
           highNibble = yourByte >>>> 4
           01010110 >>> 4 = 00000101


          IF you use this Example Byte: High[1101][0110]Low
          highNibble = yourByte >>> 4
          11010110 >>> 4 = 00000101
          Because >>> removes the signed bit.
```

Comment: Actually I only know how to turn the Signed Byte into an Unsigned Byte int anUnsignedByte = (int) b & 0xff; But i don't really know whats going on.

Comment: Yes. Please note that it is >>> and not >>>>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) It depends on the endianness. It will either be `(b[4] << 8) | b[5]` or `(b[5] << 8) | b[4]`

2) `lowNibble = yourByte & 0x0f; highNibble = (yourByte >> 4) & 0x0f;`

You can also do: `lowNibble = yourByte & 0x0f; highNibble = yourByte >>> 4;`

The unsigned shift (`>>>`) fills the upper bits with zero, regardless of the sign.

Comment: Byte = 11111111    by doing &0x0F you get 00001111
Byte = 11111111    by doing >> 4 you get  11110000 then what does the 0x0f do ?  Sorry for being dull just not getting it clearly yet.

Comment: By doing 11111111 >> 4 you get 10001111 because of the sign. Anding with 0x0f gets rid of the one caused by the sign. Note that 01111111 >> 4 = 00000111 because the sign bit was not set.

Comment: Byte: High[0101][0110]Low
lowNibble = yourbyte & 0x0f;
01010110 & 0x0f (00001111) = 00000110 
highNibble = yourByte >>>> 4
01010110 >>> 4 = 00000101

IF Byte: High[1101][0110]Low
highNibble = yourByte >>> 4
11010110 >>> 4 = 00000101
Because >>> removes the signed bit.

Comment: I don't understand the question in your last comment

Comment: it was just an example to check i got it correct i will put in the question as the formatting is brutal in the comments

Comment: I didn't know if it was a question or a statement :-) But I think you got it right. Of course, the final answer is in testing it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23846/discussion-between-devilcode-and-eduardo)